# Why is the Cycles render of my worn-edge material different from the viewport?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, materials

I'm trying to figure out edge wear with nodes and in the viewport I think it looks good.

Once it renders it's completely different for whatever reason: the worn area appears to be wider.

I'm rendering with good quality settings so I can't chalk it up to noise or low resolution.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably have a Subdivision Surface modifier with the *Render* subdivisions settings being higher than the *Viewport* subdivision: the edges are rounded more deeply in render, which affects your shading.

Example: the difference a level of subdivision can make, especially when using *Pointiness* as a texture source

[image]

**When tweaking your shader**, especially if the shader is geometry-dependent, **make sure to match *Render* and *Viewport* subdivisions** in your modifiers to preview your rendered results more accurately.

Comment: bingo, that was absolutely it. it's just one of those little settings that gets overlooked sometimes. thank you very much, nicola!